# PHP Save array value

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using the $user->groups in Joomla 3.4.5 to get the array of assigned groups specific to a user, but is there a way to get the Access Levels instead? I'd like to check specific assigned ACL instead of groups. I haven't been able to find it on the J Docs.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to locate where the Access levels are stored in the database either. If somebody knows what table they are in, I'd appreciate that information as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the proper way to retrieve a Joomla user's access levels:

```
$levels = JFactory::getUser()->getAuthorisedViewLevels();
```

print_r ($levels);